# Javascript bar in bar chart with dual axis

Tags: javascript

Can anyone recommend a good source to create a graph like the following -

[image]

This chart is actually from Excel, but I would like to use this on a web project using javascript..

Hopefully someone could advise on a source?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Thanks but that isn't quite the same, the highcharts model has only a bar in bar for one axis and another for the other axis, this example above uses both axis with on group of bars

Comment: [d3 Js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), also there exist more complicated charts

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy to accomplish in ZingChart. Here's a demo I put together based on your image. Scroll down and run the snippet to see the live demo.

Disclaimer* I'm on the ZingChart team. Comment if you have questions!

```js
var myConfig = {
  theme:"none",
  type: "bar", 
  scaleY:{
    values: "0:120:20"
  },
  plot:{
    shadow:false,
    barsOverlap:"100%"
  },
  scaleY2:{
    values:"0:700:100",
    guide:{
      visible:false
    }
 },
 scaleX:{
    guide:{
      visible:false
    }
  },
 series : [
  {
   values : [89,108,46,31,8,8,5,1],
    barWidth:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#C0504D",
    valueBox:{
      color:"black"
    },
   hoverState:{
      visible:false
    }
  },
  {
    values: [410,115,108,115,615,105,250,90],
    barWidth:"20%",
    scales:"scale-x,scale-y-2",
    backgroundColor:"#9BBB59",
    hoverState:{
      visible:false
    }
  },
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: Only comment I have is that the tooltip doesn't work correctly, it works on some of the bars on the right, but not on the left ?